# Adding System.Data.SQLite through NuGet doesn't add a reference to the project

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, xamarin, package, nuget

I'm trying to make a very simple Xamarin.Forms test application to explore some features of the [System.Data.SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) package (namely encryption). However, I can't seem to get Visual Studio 2012 to add a reference to the package to the project.

Here are the steps I am taking:

1. Created a new Xamarin.Forms Portable blank app.
2. Right-click on TestApp (core project) and select Manage NuGet Packages
3. Search for "sqlite"
4. Install the "System.Data.SQLite (x86/x64)" package. (This package is version 1.0.97.0 and it is described as "the official SQLite database engine for both x86 and x64 along with the ADO.NET provider.")
5. According to NuGet, the package was successfully installed.

However, I cannot see the reference added under my project's "References" folder, and I also cannot write "using System.Data.SQLite" without errors ("cannot resolve symbol 'Data'"). Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

On a side note, I can follow the exact same process described above except instead of creating a Xamarin.Forms Portable blank app, I choose a regular C# console app. This allows me to install the NuGet package fine and it shows up in references as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting an update to share what I've learned.

So as Jason sort of alluded to in his answer, the reason I was not able to reference the package in my Xamarin.Forms project is because Xamarin.Forms is, by definition, a PCL project. It's meant to work on all platforms. The package I was referring to in my question is not a PCL, which means that anything in the package that is platform dependent is inaccessable (which is basically the entire package). The SQLite.Net-PCL package is basically the same thing as System.Data.SQLite, but in PCL form, which means it is compatible for use in a Xamarin.Forms project.

Following this logic, it makes sense that I was able to access System.Data.SQLite from a console project, since a console project is not a PCL project and it targets a specific platform.

Answer (score 0):

For PCL projects, use [SQLite.Net-PCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL/).

Comment: That is one of the SQLite packages that I'm researching. It doesn't look like it supports database encryption, though, and I absolutely need to be able to encrypt my database. I would consider using that package with SQLCipher, but I'm not sure if they are compatible with each other.